# Insert a div + link + image inside an echo (Joomla)

Tags: php, html, echo

I'm having a little problem here and I would much appreciate your help.

I'm trying to create a sort of menu which will be displayed after a user logs in in Joomla (the fact that is joomla doesn't really matter though).  I have two different outputs for two different users.  If the user is User A, s/he will see output A, if it's user B, s/he will see output B.

I have already figured out how to do the "Look who's the user---give output" part.  And it's working perfectly.  The problem is the output itself.  I'm trying to echo a div which contains an image and a text, both as a link.  However, the only output I'm getting is the text, whith no format whatsoever.

Here it's the code:

```
<?php 

$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->id == 291) {

 echo <<<EOS

<div class="mitribu"><a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;layout=blog&amp;id=13"><img class="mitribuimg" src="images/banners/books.png" alt="books"/>Mi tribu</a></div>

EOS;

}

?>
```

As you see this should render an image and the text Mi tribu, and that should be a link.  But the only thing I'm getting is Mi tribu in plain text.

What Am I doing wrong here?

Thank you very much in advance!

Hernan.

---

EDIT: I have found the answer.  It was the plugin used to render PHP inside articles and modules in Joomla, Sourcerer, which was stripping the code.  Just in case someone else has the same problem, here it's the solution:

You must use {source 0} {/source} to add the code.  Adding the 0 tells the plugin to do not strip the HTML code.

Comment: We cannot reproduce your problem since we have no working example (JSFiddle). Maybe the image reference is broken? Find this out with Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening it in Google Chrome? Then rightclick where the image should be (so on the text) and choose "inspect element" from the menu.
This will bring up the debugging tools from Google Chrome, and will allow you to see what's been output to the browser, and might show you why your image is not visible (wrong path or something alike).

Comment: Yes, I did.  This is the output:

<div class="module mod-line  deepest" style="min-height: 143px; ">

Mi tribu
  
</div>

Which means, is not taking the div into consideration at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute HTML inside of php code easily like this below.  Instead of using { } just use the colon and output the html below.

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->id == 291):
?>

<div class="mitribu"><a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;layout=blog&amp;id=13"><img class="mitribuimg" src="images/banners/books.png" alt="books"/>Mi tribu</a></div>

<?php endif;?>
```

or do this, make sure to use the ' because you are using " in your HTML.

```
<?php 

$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->id == 291) {



echo '<div class="mitribu"><a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;layout=blog&amp;id=13"><img class="mitribuimg" src="images/banners/books.png" alt="books"/>Mi tribu</a></div>'

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks you, but I've found the answer.  The problem was the plugin used to render the PHP in a joomla module/article, Sourcerer, which was stripping the code.  I'm sorry for bothering with this.